# Why is spring-kafka silently not reading messages from kafka topics in our prod environment?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have a service using spring-kafka (v2.9.8) that reads messages from kafka topics.  The same code has been running fine for quite a while without change.

About a month ago, we found that this service was no longer getting messages from the production kafka servers.  The same service runs in multiple nonprod servers, and it's working perfectly fine, getting messages from the nonprod kafka topics. There are no errors in the prod log, it just never gets any messages.  We have double-checked the list of "bootstrap-servers", and it is apparently correct.  We have checked the wmtopic and group-id properties, and they are also correct.  Otherwise, the nonprod properties are identical to the prod properties.

I tried to turn up the log level for spring-kafka, but I still see nothing of significance in the log.

I'm at a loss to see how to troubleshoot this.  Is there some way to make it more verbose, either spring-kafka or kafka, to give us a clue for why it's not getting any messages?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have several consumers for this topic and the same group? So, an instance you look into doesn't get records because they are consumed in other instances.

Comment: Use `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` with the group id you've provided in the values

Comment: So I used this on both our nonprod and prod cluster. The nonprod test seemed to work perfectly, showing info on topics associated with the groupid. In the prod test, most of the servers returned "Error: Consumer group 'xxx'  does not exist.". One of them simply got a timeout error. If it got that "does not exist" error, is it certain that it was able to reach the server (no firewall block), and this really means that the groupid doesn't exist?

Comment: Actually, I also figured out that I can use the "--list" option to simply list the groupids available on each server. This provides even more convincing information that it's able to reach the prod servers, but the groupid they gave us for the prod servers simply doesn't exist, contrary to what they told us.

Comment: The person who manages the kafka server is saying that "Basically group id will be created by client. If your client creates group id then it will show there." As far as I know, we've never had to manually "create" anything. If we start the service using spring-kafka, pointing to the listed servers and with the groupid and topic properties, does it implicitly "create" the groupid, or is he just completely wrong?